# Merging Depth Maps for multi view stereo?

Tags: graphics, image-processing, computer-vision, stereo-3d

Is there a simple to implement way of merging depth maps? I take pictures of a statue from 3 different positions .Then each stereo pair produces a disparity map.I re-project it to depth using triangulation .Finally I get 3 set of 3d points.How can I merge them into one 3d model?

Comment: You asked 42 questions and never voted. Is the community failing to produce good (or bad) answers to your questions, or are you just forgetting to vote?

Comment: @belisarius: Had not registered.Have done that now .Will vote.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess Iterative Closest Point algorithm can be employed for this.